# ScrollView horizontal in React Native cut my text

Tags: android, react-native, scrollview

i using scroll view horizontal to scroll text in row
but the text begain out of the screen

this is my code

```
  <ScrollView
    ref={(scrollView) => { this._scrollView = scrollView; }}
    horizontal={true}
    showsHorizontalScrollIndicator={false}
    showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
    automaticallyAdjustContentInsets={false}
    directionalLockEnabled={true}
    bounces={false}
    scrollsToTop={false}
  >
```

this is what happend:

[image]

in the right side the text cut and i can scroll from left to right the text...
what i need to do?

tnx a lot

Comment: Did you manage to figure it out?

Answer (score 0):

use HorizontalScrollView to be able to scroll the text horizontally

Comment: ahh, I though you were using android sdk.

Comment: when i using contentContainerStyle={{marginLeft: -50}} its help to return the text but its not genric solution ...

Answer (score 0):

I guess one of the scroll containers width is bigger than the screen width, which causes the scroll to expand beyond the screen width.
See [this rnplay example](https://rnplay.org/apps/ecg7eQ) which I made which works great (Also works with Hebrew letters).